# How to compute CRC (checksum) for array of struct?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, md5, checksum

I have a struct with 2 bytes inside. How to compute checksum (e.g. MD5 hash) for array of such structs?

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public byte Byte1;
    public byte Byte2;
}

public class MyClass
{
    public static byte[] ComputeChecksum(MyStruct[] myStructs)
    {
        // TODO: calculation.
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? it *looks* like you should be able to simply loop over the array, applying any chosen hash algorithm to the two fields. As an aside: exposing public fields is *usually* bad, and having mutable (changeable) fields on a struct is *usually* bad...

Comment: Another aside: *[CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)*, *[checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum)* and *[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)* are not the same thing.

Comment: I just wanted to put my array of struct as array of bytes to MD5 calculation method, which accept only byte[] and MemoryStream.

Comment: Okay, forget about CRC and MD5. How to treat array of a struct as array of raw bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do you want STRONG digesting or just a quick error-check/consistent-lookup value?

MD5/SHA is pretty intensive operations - they're built around block-structures that are multiples of hundreds of bytes.

fletcher and CRC32 are very efficient and do a decent job of producing a random number.. What they are not good at is having random bit positions.. So for example, you wouldn't want a fletcher than only look at only the upper or bottom 8 bits (since there would be too little varience)..

Either find an open-source library or hit wikipedia for the various algorithms.. I tend to just use something like:

```
  u32 hash_mystruct(mystruct[] data, u32 count) {
      return hash((u8*)data, sizeof(mystruct) * count);
  }
  u32 hash(u8* data, u32 size) {    
    u32 hash = 19;
    for (u32 i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      u8 c = *data++;
      if (c != 0) { // usually when doing on strings this wouldn't be needed
        hash *= c;
      }
      hash += 7;
    }
  }
```